# Absolute divs background color isn't covering the entire screen

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am trying to put a loading screen to my VueJs app by using divs only and the problem is I am not able to make the divs(loadingScreen) background color to cover the entire screen. Instead, it covers as much as the loaders height. I have already tried adding margin to the body but that didn't resolve the issue.

```css
#ctrl {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  top: 40%;
}

#loadingScreen {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

#loader {
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  z-index: inherit;
}

#playPause{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="ctrl">
  <div id="playPause">
    <img src="../public/pauseButton.png" />
    <img src="../public/playButton.png" />
  </div>
  <div id="loadingScreen">
    <div id="loader"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please make a clarity on your question ,you want to fill the loader with background color black to the entire screen?

Comment: @PRAJINPRAKASH I have edited my question and yeah, that is what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perceived behavior is expected as the loading screen is a child of the `ctrl` element. This is not an issue, i just changed the loading screen position to fixed and manipulated its positional properties, see below. Then i just centered the loader.

```css
#ctrl {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  left: 50%;
  top: 40%;
}

#loadingScreen {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
}

#loader {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  z-index: 5;
}

#playPause{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="ctrl">
  <div id="playPause">
    content
  </div>
  <div id="loadingScreen">
    <div id="loader"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works as expected. I think removing the left:0, right:0 and transform properties is not effecting the result. Only margin-left and margin right properties were enough.

Comment: By the way, in older browsers, the loader is aligning in the top of the screen. Why is that the case?

Comment: @AEB, not sure, can be browser specific. None if these css properties are 'new'

Comment: I have setted up height and width property of the loadingscreen to 1oo% and it works for now.